# jQuery fadeIn when done loading each individual DIV with image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that displays alot of pictures. Instead of showing them and watching it load, is there a way to fade it in after it's done loading? Kinda new to the wonderful world of jQuery and javascript.

Right now I get data from a PHP file which calls the mySQL server and gets the latest images. It just returns a big block of HTML to display:

```
// If the user clicks the logo
$("#logo").click(function() {
$("#right_bar_wrapper").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, '200');
var thePostData = "username=c";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myflashpics.com/v2/process_newsfeed.php",
  data: thePostData,
  success: function(theRetrievedData) {
    document.getElementById('right_bar_wrapper').innerHTML = theRetrievedData;
    $("#right_bar_wrapper").fadeIn("200");

  }
});
});
```

Here's what ONE div looks like that contains each image:

```
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed'> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info makeProfileAppear' id='user_coultonvento'><img src='http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=kmdp&size=thumbnail' />TheAmazingCoultoniusTheFourneeth...</div> 
<img src='http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=6v9o&size=big' id='image_6v9o' class='makePictureBig' style='width: 180px;' /> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments' style='float: right; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: 20px; display: none;' id='bigpicture_comment_6v9o'>9</div> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_caption'>Usama bin laden? I believe that's a typo, Fox. </div> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments' id='littlepicture_comment_6v9o'>9</div> 
<div style='clear: both;'></div> 
</div><div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed'> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info makeProfileAppear' id='user_BrandonVento'><img src='http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=e4r7&size=thumbnail' />Brandon Vento</div> 
<img src='http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=o1sk&size=big' id='image_o1sk' class='makePictureBig' style='width: 180px;' /> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments' style='float: right; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: 20px; display: none;' id='bigpicture_comment_o1sk'>9</div> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_caption'></div> 
<div class='sidebar_image_box_newsfeed_user_info_comments' id='littlepicture_comment_o1sk'>9</div> 
<div style='clear: both;'></div> 
</div>
```

Sure, it fades in but the user sees it load.

What would the best way to do this be?

Thanks, 
 Coulton

Comment: What do you mean by the see it load?

Comment: @Nick: Watch the image load. In Google Chrome, you see the top of the image and you slowly start to see the rest of the image. What about hiding it until it's loaded and have it fade in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery image .load() function to do that

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myflashpics.com/v2/process_newsfeed.php",
  data: thePostData,
  success: function(theRetrievedData) {
    document.getElementById('right_bar_wrapper').innerHTML = theRetrievedData;
    $("#right_bar_wrapper").fadeIn("200");
    //here do some trick
    $("#right_bar_wrapper img").load(function(){ 
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

or you can use live() to bind dynamic img elements

Comment: ah yes :) thanks for comment, very good. Coulton, you know right? what Andre is telling.

Answer (score 2):

Load the img tags with style='display:none' and bind the load() event of the image to fade it in. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Sample:

```
$(".makePictureBig").live('load', function(){ 
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: How would I do this if I have multiple images? I want to fade each one in individually and not all at the same time, if that makes sense.

Comment: the load() will be called individually after each image is loaded

Comment: It's not getting called when a image is loaded. Put a `alert();` in and it never came up. What could be the possible problem? Is there a specific library?

Answer (score 1):

Firs, use .load() instead of ajax, as it is simpler to use

Then, as a callback of load() function, bind fadeIn() to the load event

```
$("#logo").click(function() {
  $("#right_bar_wrapper")
    .animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, '200')
    .load( "http://myflashpics.com/v2/process_newsfeed.php",
           {"username" : "c"},
           function() {
               $(this).bind('load',function(){
                  $(this).fadeIn("200");
               });
           }
  );
});
```

Comment: Hm.. Didn't work. None of my JS is working.. Maybe the issue is with the syntax?

Comment: It had an extra }, which I already fixed. Try now, if does not work, please provide a fiddle

Comment: Again, it was a typo. I forgot to close the bind function. Glad you already solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.. use the load()

You can execute a function when an image has completed loading (unhide the containing div).

Take a look at this example
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/08/05/jquery-check-whether-image-is-loaded/